# NSArray of NSDictionary in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to develop a function to add Dictionaries into Arrays.

This function looks this way but doesn't work:

in the implementation of the `CBLModel` I have the property `emailList`. The property I want to be an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`'s.

```
-(void) addEmail: (NSDictionary*) c{
    NSMutableArray* mutArrayEmail= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject: self.emailList];
    [mutArrayEmail addObject:c];
    self.emailList = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mutArrayEmail];  
}
```

And the implementation would be something like:

```
[persInf addEmail: email1];
[persInf addEmail: email2];
[persInf addEmail: email3];
```

Any help?

**EDIT**

Thanks to everyone for your reply.

I have inserted in the main code the following (in order to not test everything easier):

```
NSDictionary *inventory = @{
                            @"Mercedes-Benz SLK250" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:13],
                            @"Mercedes-Benz E350" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:22],
                            @"BMW M3 Coupe" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:19],
                            @"BMW X6" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],

                            };
NSMutableArray *nsmut= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[nsmut addObject: inventory];
[nsmut addObject: inventory];
[nsmut addObject: inventory];
NSArray *nsarray= [NSArray arrayWithArray:nsmut];

[persInf setEmailList:nsarray];
```

After this I get an error. I post this code sample as may be easier to see where the error can be

Comment: Yep, you need to create the array only once, and `emailList` needs to be declared as a Mutable array.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks a lot , but I can't declare it as Mutable array or it won't work in the CBLModel

Comment: Why not?  You can use an NSMutableArray anywhere you can use an NSArray.

Answer (score 3):

You only want to create the array if it doesn't already exist:

```
- (void)addEmail:(NSDictionary *) c{
    if (!self.emailList) {
        self.emailList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self.emailList addObject:c];
}
```

This is *lazy initialization* as the array is created on first use.  This is fine, as long as you realise that the array can be `nil` at times in the object's lifetime (which is less of a problem in Objective-C than in other languages).

A more conventional approach is to override an `init` method and allocate the array there.

Comment: Good answer. Probably worth noting that `self.emailList` needs to be an `NSMutableArray` (from the OP's code it appears to be an `NSArray`).

Comment: @BlackRider Yeah I suspected that too, however he does allocate an `NSMutableArray` so I think he understands that.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for your time and patience. I need to use emailList as an NSArray as CBLModel doesn't accept NSMutableArray.

Comment: @user3009804 Sorry, I've missed the point with that last comment.  You'll have to make the instance variable an `NSMutableArray` to allow you to add items to it after creation.

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks a lot once again! I have edited the question and added a code sample so could be easily seen. I am trying my best but this still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `NSMutableArray` outside of your `addEmail:` method. You can use `addObject:` as-is.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your repply, but I can't declare it as NSMutableArray. For inserting data to the Database CBLModel doesn't accept NSMutableArray, but NSArray

Answer (score 0):

Since `emailList` is a property you should override the getter to lazily instantiate it when its needed, like so.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)emailList {
  if(!_emailList) {
    _emailList = [NSMutableArray array];
  }
  return _emailList
}
```

To be thorough you could write that code using the ternary and make it a bit shorter:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)emailList {
  return _emailList = _emailList ?: [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

Finally once you've overrode the getter your `addEmail` method becomes:

```
- (void)addEmail: (NSDictionary*)c {
[self.emailList addObject:c];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to store emailList as an NSArray, I guess you need to set it with

```
self.emailList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutArrayEmail];
```

I'm far from an expert, though, so there may be problems with this approach.  I'd welcome comments to that effect!

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'CBLModel required, but got __NSDictionaryI 0x769ef20'

Comment: Sounds like the error is not in setting emailList, but in what is being done with the elements of the array.  I'm not familiar with CBL, so maybe I'm missing the point here.  Are you sure you want an array of dictionaries and not an array of CBLModel's?

Comment: @user3009804 - That error says that you were supposed to pass a CBLModel object (on whatever call it was where the failure was flagged).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare additional property of NSMutableArray (it can be in your class extension):

```
@property(nonatomic, copy)NSMutableArray *tempArray;
```

Initialize it in the init

```
_tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And change your setter method to:

```
-(void) addEmail: (NSDictionary*) c{
[self.tempArray addObject:c];
}
```

And change your getter to:

```
- (NSArray *)emailList {
return [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.tempArray copy]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are new to SO, so a little (friendly!) advice: you need to provide more detail in your questions of exactly what you've tried and what has gone wrong; e.g. "After this I get an error." does not help others help you.

Now reading your question and comments two things pop out: assertions about `CBLModel`, and how to add items to an array.

A. First, `CBLModel`. You've stated a few times you need an `NSArray` as:

> I can't declare it as Mutable array or it won't work in the CBLModel

What do you mean by this? If you are saying that the methods in `CBLModel` take `NSArray` type arguments then you *can* pass `NSMutableArray`'s as an `NSMutableArray` *is an* `NSArray` (i.e. it is a subclass) - this is one of the central pillars of inheritance-based languages like Objective-C.

If instead you mean that `CBLModel` does not function correctly if you pass it an `NSMutableArray`, say because you yourself mutate the array after passing it and that effects `CBLModel` in an invalid way[*], then you can simply create an immutable copy (`[NSArray arrayWithArray:someMutableArray]`) or just another mutable copy (`[someMutableArray copy]`) which you pass *only* to `CBLModel`.

B. Adding items to an array. Let's look at your code, line by line, so you can see what it is doing:

```
NSMutableArray* mutArrayEmail= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject: self.emailList];
```

This creates a new `NSMutableArray` initialised with a *single element* obtained from `self.emailList`, and stores a reference to it in `mutArrayEmail`. E.g. if before execution `self.emailList` references an array `[1, 2, 3]`, then after execution `mutArrayEmail` references a (mutable) array `[ [1, 2, 3] ]` - a *single element* array whose element is itself an array.

```
[mutArrayEmail addObject:c];
```

You add the object referenced by `c`, so using the same example you now have `[ [1, 2, 3], c ]` - an array with *two elements*.

```
self.emailList = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mutArrayEmail];
```

And finally you create a new array with the *single* object referenced by `mutArrayEmail`. Keeping the same example you now have `[ [ [1, 2, 3], c ] ]`. That is probably not what you wanted, or what `CBLModel` accepts.

The class method `arrayWithArray:` creates an array with the same elements as another array. If you used that method the above example would produce `[1, 2, 3, c]`, which is probably what you want.

HTH

---

[*] Any classes which accept objects of types with mutable subtypes [arrays, strings, etc.] would normally be written such that a mutation after the object is passed does not effect the behaviour in undesirable ways, i.e. the classes would copy objects if needed. This it is recommended that properties of such type are defined with the `copy` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea, generally, to expose a mutable array to the outside world if it's part of an object's state.  It means the object's state can be amended without the object knowing about it.

Here's how I would do this:

Have a readonly property that lets people get the array.

Have a method to add objects to the array.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSArray* emailList;

-(void) addEmail: (NSDictionary*) newEmail;

@end
```

In the implementation, have an **mutable** instance variable to back the property, initialise it in your designated initialiser.  Implement your add method.

```
// All code assumed to be using ARC

@implementation MyClass
{
    NSMutableArray* _emailList;
}

@synthesize emailList = _emailList;

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _emailList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) addEmail: (NSDictionary*) newEmail
{
    [_emailList addObject: newEmail];
}

@end
```

Although, the actual object returned by the property is an `NSMutableArray` the rule is to program to the interface, which means that when an interface says it returns an immutable object, even if you know it's really a mutable subclass, you are not allowed to send it mutating methods.

If, however, you are paranoid, implement the getter for the property like this:

```
-(NSArray*) emailList
{
    return [_emailList copy];
}
```